# Find method works in UDF when called in another sub but does not work when used in Excel Sheet

Tags: vba

I'm writing a code that will search for the specific position of a value's occurence in a range. My approach is to do a loop using the Find method on a predefined search range based on the input and add each find result to a collection. However, when I call the UDF in another sub, the code works as intended but when put in Excel it returns 0, with the same inputs. I tried F8 through the UDF in Excel and apparently the Find Method returns nothing when used in Excel while it works normally when the UDF is called by another sub. I have included the code below. Any input would be greatly appreciated.

```
    Public Function CROSSEDVOLUME(dt As Variant, datarange As Range, date_col As Long, real_vol_col As Long, abs_vol_col As Long) As Double
    Dim filtered_arr() As Variant
    Dim i As Long, coll As Collection
    Dim ori_col As Long, ori_row As Long
    Dim find_res As Range, search_range As Range, first_occur As String

    ori_row = datarange.Cells(1, 1).Row
    ori_col = datarange.Cells(1, 1).column


    Set coll = New Collection

    'Setting search range
    Set search_range = Range(datarange.Cells(1, date_col), 
    datarange.Cells(datarange.Rows.count, date_col))

    If search_range.Cells(1, 1).Value = dt Then
        coll.Add 1
        first_occur = search_range.Cells(1, 1).Address
    End If

    Set find_res = search_range.Find(dt, search_range.Cells(1, 1), xlValues, xlWhole, xlByRows, xlNext, False, False)

    'Code stucks here

    If find_res Is Nothing Then
        CROSSEDVOLUME = 0
        Exit Function
    Else
        If find_res.Address <> search_range.Cells(1, 1).Address Then
            first_occur = IIf(first_occur = "", find_res.Address, first_occur)
            coll.Add find_res.Row - ori_row + 1
            Set find_res = search_range.Find(dt, find_res, xlValues, xlWhole, xlByRows, xlNext, False, False)

            Do While Not find_res Is Nothing And find_res.Address <> first_occur
                coll.Add find_res.Row - ori_row + 1
                Set find_res = search_range.Find(dt, find_res, xlValues, xlWhole, xlByRows, xlNext, False, False)
            Loop
        End If
    End If

    CROSSEDVOLUME = coll.count

    End Function
```

Comment: hi, i dont see where u are defining the sheet that u want to use. i believe that the button in excel is not in the sheet that u want to evaluate, correct ?

Comment: There's no button in Excel. It's a UDF so I just put the function in a cell with the inputs and run it. I have tested with the watch window that the code recognises the correct sheet when used in Excel, it's just the find method that keeps turning nothing that poses a problem.